Which episode of Top Gear is this?
I recently went through and watched the two amphibious cars episodes (s8 e3, s10 e2).  I greatly enjoy those episodes.  However, I have an image in my head that I swore was from those episodes, but I just can't place it.
The image is of the guys out on the water, and one of them (May, I believe) gets lost and/or stranded/stuck.  He's lost because they're going through these craggy rocks/island things, and are trying to get to some building (like a bar or something).  I can't remember what they were on, but I could have sworn they were on their amphibious cars.
Does anyone have any idea what I'm talking about?

I think you're looking for 'The one with the trip to Vietnam'
They ride mopeds the length of Vietnam and then have to turn them into boats to reach a bar in the water.
